# Vimeo not showing fullscreen option in Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, vimeo

here is my case I have this shared code in Xamarin.Forms, its rendered well in iOS platform but in android

[image]

iOS platform

[image]

My ContentPage

```
public class LocalHtml : ContentPage
    {
        public LocalHtml()
        {
            var browser = new CookieWebView();

            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
<h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>

<iframe src=""https://player.vimeo.com/video/236787722"" style=""background-color: #000000"" width=""360"" height=""200"" frameborder=""0"" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</html>";

            browser.Source = htmlSource;
            Content = browser;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you solve this?